# Sum of a field with respect to another field

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table of employees Salary named as **empSalary**.

[image: empSalary]

I want to calculate sum of salaries issued by each department.
What comes to my mind is

```
Select sum(Salary) from empSalary where deptId = (Select deptId from empSalary)
```

This statement gives me **5100** which is the sum of Salary where **deptId = 1**.
How is this possible using only sql query?
Sorry for the question title as i was unable to find words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to `GROUP BY` the Department:

```
SELECT Dept_ID
      ,sum(Salary) Total_Salary
FROM empSalary
GROUP BY Dept_ID
```

Comment: Thanks. That was easy i think ;). What was the mistake in my statement? Can you tell me?

Comment: `WHERE` is used to limit results, without a `GROUP BY` clause you'll only get one resulting row when selecting an aggregate. Some databases require a single value be returned when `WHERE field =` is used, and if multiple values are desired it requires `WHERE field IN`.  However, if you used `WHERE IN` in your query it'd return the total of all salaries and would be no different than `SELECT SUM(Salary) FROM empSalary`.  You need the `GROUP BY ` to break an aggregate into sets.

Answer (score 1):

This is exact use of group by , you make groups and and each group you can calculate sum, average, min , max or count

```
select DeptID, Sum(Salary) as SumSalary
From empSalary
Group by DeptID
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, "[group by](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html)" in SQL helps here.

```
      Select sum(Salary) from empSalary group by DeptID;
```